# PUBLIC Schema in Snowflake Database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-schema

A Public schema is created when we create a database and tables are created under Public schema if we don't specify any schema.

Will I face any issues if I drop the Public schema from the database as I don't want anyone to create tables under it?

Answer (score 2):

Technically nothing stands in the way of removing it.

I am deliberately dropping the Public schema from new databases, because I want users to come up with more meaningful names. This way we avoid having this general purpose schema. It requires more care and thoughtfulness from developers, which I find productive.

If you take a Snowflake University course, you will notice that they are doing exactly the same thing - when a task requires creating new database, the very next step is dropping the PUBLIC schema and creating one or more schemas witch some valuable names.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping public schema is not a good choice.
That's the behaviors of snowflake to create table in the public schema to when user haven't specified the schema. So do a role based access control if you don't wanted to use public schema.

Comment: Thanks Arun. Can you please elaborate on why deletion is not a good choice?

Comment: FWIW I disagree with the statement "Dropping public schema is not a good choice". I would not want to allow tables to be created without specifying a schema.